# When did the idea of free will begin? Same for determinism

Tags: aristotle, free-will, plato, determinism, socrates

Hey so I'm doing this free will v determinism thing for class and I've tried but I can't seem to find when the separate beliefs came about. I know Socrates and Aristotle had something to do with them but my searches give me no dates. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you effectively asking for the oldest written sources with reference to these concepts we know of? Or when they may have occurred in history? Which cultural environments are we talking about (European, Asian, ...)? Please try to be more specific in your question (as you'll have to be in your assignment)

Comment: See [History of the Free Will Problem](http://www.informationphilosopher.com/freedom/history/) on Information Philosopher. Do not expect any dates, we do not know when exactly people wrote their works in ancient times. The best you can do is give approximate life dates of the authors mentioned, they can be found in Wikipedia. The term "determinism" is recent, mid 19th century, see [History of the study of indeterminism in classical mechanics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/2680/55). Historically, fatalism and necessitarianism were similar, but without the modern connection to physical laws.

Comment: The Greeks of old did not conceive will as a separate faculty; it was developed rather late. *The Will and Human Action: From Antiquity to the Present* has a most enlightening 1st chapter by R. Sorabji.